Is there a way to remove items from unstable_cache in nextJS
E.g following is my function is my API route on GET. How can I remove a user from unstable_cache with id of x on a delete route.
export const GET = async (request: Request, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const getUser = async (id: string) => {            
    // user get implementation
    return user;
  };
  // get cached data
  const cachedData = unstable_cache(async (id) => getUser(id), ['user', params.id], 60000);
  const data = await cachedData(params.id);
  return NextResponse.json(data);
}


Use revalidateTag - When using unstable_cache you add the tags "user" and params.id. You can reuse those tags to clear only cached data with these specific tags.
In your instance use revalidateTag(params.id) to clear a specific user, or revalidateTag('user) to remove all cached users.
